# How to use the Sendgrid.d.ts to use sendgrid?

Tags: node.js, typescript, compilation, sendgrid, typescript-typings

I'm having the same problem as [Chris P with his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446199/typescript-definitions-for-sendgrid), and I understand a bit more about why [my issue here happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317786/typescript-compilation-doesnt-add-require-statement-to-some-files/39325473#39325473).

I have sendgrid installed via npm and then typings, and my node_modules has a sendgrid dir and my typings has a global/sendgrid dir.

When I use sendgrid (via 'npm install sendgrid' - straight js, not ts) my working code looks like:

```
var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
var from_email = new helper.Email('dina@dfberry.io');
var to_email = new helper.Email('berry.dina@gmail.com');
var subject = 'Hello World from the SendGrid Node.js Library!';
var content = new helper.Content('text/plain', 'Hello, Email!');
var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);

var sg = require('sendgrid')("SG.TJKAFkv..THIS..IS..THE...KEY");
var request = sg.emptyRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/v3/mail/send',
  body: mail.toJSON(),
});

sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.body);
  console.log(response.headers);
});
```

When I look at the sendgrid/index.d.ts ( via 'typings install dt~sendgrid --global --save'), I see two modules, Sendgrid & 'sendgrid'. Why are there two modules?

```
//sendgrid/index.d.ts
// Generated by typings
// Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/ac94ea73311e9d5607f919b5c174d66d72c78a29/sendgrid/sendgrid-1.1.0.d.ts
declare module Sendgrid {
    //#region Options

    export interface UriParts {
        protocol: string;
        host: string;
        port: string;
        endpoint: string;
    }

    export interface Options {
        protocol?: string;
        host?: string;
        port?: string;
        endpoint?: string;
        uri?: string;
        proxy?: string;
        web?: {
            pool?: any;
        }
    }

    export interface OptionsExport {
        uriParts: UriParts;
        uri: string;

        proxy?: string;
        web?: {
            pool?: any;
        }
    }

    //#endregion

    //#region Email

    export interface EmailOptions {
        to?: any;
        toname?: string;
        from?: string;
        fromname?: string;
        subject?: string;
        text?: string;
        html?: string;
        bcc?: any;
        replyto?: string;
        date?: Date;
        headers?: { [key: string]: string };
        files?: FileHandlerOptions[];
        smtpapi?: any;
    }

    export class Email {
        to: any;
        toname: string;
        from: string;
        fromname: string;
        subject: string;
        text: string;
        html: string;
        bcc: any;
        replyto: string;
        date: Date;
        headers: { [key: string]: string };
        files: FileHandler[];
        smtpapi: any;

        constructor();
        constructor(options: EmailOptions);

        addTo(address: string): void;
        addHeader(type: string, value: string): void;
        addSubstitution(type: string, value: string): void;
        addSubstitution(type: string, value: string[]): void;
        addSection(section: { [key: string]: string }): void;
        addUniqueArg(uarg: { [key: string]: string }): void;
        addCategory(category: string): void;
        addFilter(filter: string, command: string, value: number): void;
        addFilter(filter: string, command: string, value: string): void;
        addFile(file: FileHandlerOptions): void;

        setFrom(address: string): void;
        setSubject(subject: string): void;
        setText(text: string): void;
        setHtml(html: string): void;
        setHeaders(headers: { [key: string]: string }): void;
        setSubstitutions(substitutions: { [key: string]: string[] }): void;
        setSections(sections: { [key: string]: string }): void;
        setUniqueArgs(uargs: { [key: string]: string }): void;
        setCategories(categories: string[]): void;
        setFilters(filters: any): void;
    }

    //#endregion

    //#region FileHandler

    export interface FileHandlerOptions {
        filename?: string;
        contentType?: string;
        cid?: string;
        path?: string;
        url?: string;
        content?: any;
    }

    export class FileHandler {
        filename: string;
        contentType: string;
        cid: string;

        type: string;
        content: string;
        path: string;
        url: string;

        constructor(options: FileHandlerOptions);

        loadContent(callback: HandlerCallback): void;

        static handlers: {
            content: Handler;
            path: Handler;
            url: Handler;
            none: Handler;
        };
    }

    export interface Handler {
        (file: FileHandler, callback: HandlerCallback): void;
    }

    export interface HandlerCallback {
        (hasError: boolean, error: Error): void;
        (hasError: boolean, error: string): void;
    }

    //#endregion

    //#region Sendgrid Class

    interface Constructor {
        (api_user: string, api_key: string, options?: Options): Instance;
        new (api_user: string, api_key: string, options?: Options): Instance;
    }

    export interface Instance {
        version: string;
        api_user: string;
        api_key: string;
        options: OptionsExport;
        Email: typeof Email;

        send(email: EmailOptions, callback: (err: Error, json: any) => any): void;
        send(email: Email, callback: (err: Error, json: any) => any): void;
    }

    //#endregion
}

declare module "sendgrid" {
    var ctor: Sendgrid.Constructor;
    export = ctor;
}
```

The exported stuff that I think I want to use is class Sendgrid.Email and "sendgrid".ctor.

While I realize I can make ts use my js and just be done with it, I want to understand how to use the sendgrid/index.d.ts or if I even should. The file says it is generated from typings so I assume typings ran over the node_modules sendgrid files and decided how to build it out as a d.ts file.

However, when I use ts to bring sendgrid in, it doesn't work how I think it should work.

I think I need to create the Constructor(api_user, api_key, options) and get the returned Instance. Then use the Instance.send() to send the email.

When I use VSCode, the intellisense shows the sendgrid/index.d.ts objects but when I call the compiled to js file, the objects are empty.

How do I read/use the sendgrid/index.d.ts file to write against the sendgrid and have both the intellisense (which works now) and the compiled js file work (which doesn't work now).

As you can read from [Chris's SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446199/typescript-definitions-for-sendgrid), the ts code compiles but the very first object that uses the d.ts file is undefined.

Is the d.ts file just wrong? How would I know this is in the future? Other than the intellisense, the d.ts file doesn't connect meaningfully to the underlying sendgrid library.

Comment: I think the d.ts file is either out of sync or not related to the sendgrid I think it should be related to. I'm going to build my own d.ts file from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript definitions for sendgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446199/typescript-definitions-for-sendgrid)

Answer (score 1):

> I see two modules, Sendgrid & 'sendgrid'. Why are there two modules

The `Sendgrid` defines Sendgrid in the global namespace. This allows other developers to easily add / fix features exported by the definition.

The `'sendgrid'` module is pointing to the NPM module that you can `import/require`. This provides you with safety when you do `import Sendgrid = require('sendgrid')`. This is the recommended usage (big fan of modules here).